# jquery : ul, li parent multiple child sub-child toggling

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

my main question is as follows: how to show only the first subchild of a ul or li upon clicking the enclosing parent.

eg:

```
<ul> Grandparent
  <li> Child1 <li> Grandchild11</li></li>
  <li> Child2 <li>GrandChild21</li><li>grandchild22</li></li>
</ul>
```

so, for example
I would like something to the effect of

```
$('ul').click(function(){
  $('ul').children('first li').toggle();
});
$('li').click(function(){
  $('li').children('first li').toggle();
});
```

meaning: when i click ul, i only see the first child node (child1 and child2 will be shown, but not the grandchildren). when i click child1 or child2 i see the respective grandchild.
grandchild is not shown upon clicking grandparent, only upon clicking child1 or child2.

i know i am reinventing the wheel of some pre-coded solution, but any help would be largely appreciated!

Comment: You need to wrap your child `<li>` elements in `<ul>` as well, a `<li>` can only be a child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 2 steps here, first fix the HTML to be valid (a `<li>` has to be in a `<ul>` or `<ol>`), like this:

```
<ul> 
    <li>Grandparent
        <ul>
          <li> Child1 
              <ul><li> Grandchild11</li></ul>
          </li>
          <li> Child2 
              <ul><li>GrandChild21</li><li>grandchild22</li></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Then your click handler looks like this:

```
$('li').click(function(e){
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf4yM/), they key here is [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the `event` passed into the `click` handler.  This prevents the `click` event from bubbling up, causing the parent to also toggle the children beneath them...comment out this line in the demo to see some very undesirable behavior :)

Oh, and as Mvan mentions in comments, use some CSS to hide the children initially like the demo does:

```
ul li ul { display: none; }​
```

Comment: +1 for fast solution. Be sure to include that little CSS or start off with `$('ul li ul').hide();`, else the elements will be open immediately.

Comment: @MvanGeest: Good note :) - I added the CSS I used in the demo

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`>` selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html).

Note that nesting `li` elements is not allowed. Use a `div` or something else inside the `li`.